# Xcode wont suggest my code snippets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added a simple code snippet:

[image: code snippet]

And when i'm trying to type "tablerows" in my class i get no suggestions. Tried to clean the project didnt help.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Silly question: Have you restarted Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

The completion scope is important. If you have set it to be "Class Implementation" then you have to try the shortcut in the class -- outside any methods. I hope you are doing that, since the code snippet is actually a method.

Answer (score 0):

Restart XCode completely, to apply the changes. Thanks to @Moshe

Comment: Good to hear the restarting worked. However, that is not the general case. You can create a snippet and start using it. Might be some problem occurred internally.